# file is not read by completely

Tags: c#, .net, file

I have an file text with approximate 113687 lines, but my application reads only 314 lines, can anyone say why?

My code:

```
string file = @"z:\foo.txt";
StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(file);
string line;
int rows = 0; 
while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
  ++rows; 
   doSomethingWith(line); 
  // ...
}
```

The `DoSomethingWith` function is similar to:

```
protected static bool DoSomethingWith(string line)
{
    return Regex.Match(line, @"\d+\-\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+").Success; 
}
```

**Updated:**

In answer to Gregs question:

> Does your foo.txt contain a Ctrl+Z character on line 314?

Yes, my file contains a `Control-Z` character on line 314.

Comment: Nobody can say why, since  you haven't given enough information. How do we know that `doSomethingWith(line)` doesn't count to 314 and then crash?

Comment: Does your `foo.txt` contain a Ctrl+Z character on line 314?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Text files on Windows can be terminated with a **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>** character. This means that when the file is read, the `StreamReader` returns end-of-file when the **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>** is encountered. Any data following the **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>** is not read.

If you wish to read the entire file without this text-mode behaviour, use `File.OpenRead` instead of `File.OpenText`.